# How to read a empty cell value using EXCEL interop api in C#.net?

Tags: c#-4.0, excel-2010, excel-interop

I am getting a System.com_object error if I am trying to read the EXCEL cell which is empty. My code is :

```
public static List<OrderPC> getFilters(string fileCheckout)
    {
        List<OrderPC> orderPCs = new List<OrderPC>();
        XLDoc sldoc = new XLDoc();

        string localPath = @"C:\Temp\PCs.xlsx";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL=null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook mWorkBook=null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet mWSheet1=null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange=null;
        try
        {
            oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(localPath);

            mWSheet1 = mWorkBook.Sheets[1];

            xlRange = mWSheet1.UsedRange;

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Hyperlink hl in xlRange.Hyperlinks)
            {

               int y = hl.Range.Column;

                int z = hl.Range.Row;

                string vFilter = mWSheet1.Cells[z, y + 1].Value2.Trim();

                if (vFilter.CompareTo("Weekly") == 0)
                {
                    String baseUri = "http://xxx.yyy.net?";
                    int followUpIndex = baseUri.Length;
                    OrderPC orderPc = new OrderPC();
                    orderPc.ProductClass = hl.TextToDisplay.Trim();
                    orderPc.HyperLink = hl.Address.Trim().Substring(followUpIndex);
                    orderPc.SpecType = mWSheet1.Cells[z, y - 1].Value2.Trim();
                     if (mWSheet1.Rows[z].Cells[y + 3] != null || mWSheet1.Rows[z].Cells[y + 3].Value2 != string.Empty)
                        {
                            orderPc.ManufactureDate = mWSheet1.Cells[z, y + 3].Value2.ToString(); //Here is the error**
                        }
                    //Console.WriteLine(orderPc.ProductClass+"----"+orderPc.HyperLink);

                    orderPCs.Add(orderPc);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlRange);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(mWSheet1);

            mWorkBook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(mWorkBook);

            oXL.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oXL);
        }
        return orderPCs;
    }
```

This excel file has 10 columns and I suppose I'm reading a valid cell. The error is **"

`{Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`
   `at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )` 
   `at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)`

"** I don't have any clue since its COM. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you convert this string to date: mWSheet1.Cells[z, y + 3].Value2.ToString(); and than to try it?!

Comment: It throws the above mentioned error if i do anything with the empty  cells.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add another check

```
if (mWSheet1.Cells[z, y + 3].Value2 != null)
```

or convert to string using the following code, because it would not fail if Value2 is null

```
orderPc.ManufactureDate = Convert.ToString(mWSheet1.Cells[z, y + 3].Value2);
```

Comment: It worked..i also tried orderPc.ManufactureDate = ""+mWSheet1.Cells[z, y + 3].Value2; and its working..thanks though..

Comment: Convert.ToString instead of .ToString() worked for me. This will actually solve this issue for me in many other places since I was unaware of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking your cell if it is not null, OR not string.empty.  It is pretty likely that your cell is either not null or not string.emtpy.

You need to use && instead of ||, because you only want true, if your cell is not null AND not string.empty